# How to show custom menu if BottomNavigationView is clicked?

Tags: android, android-bottomnav

Consider a BottomNavigationView like this, which shows a custom floating menu (Transfer, Payment, Commerce) if it's clicked.

[image]

I know how to use a BottomNavigationView. But what about the menu?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67897505/3466808.

Comment: Still a bit confused. Perhaps there's a more concrete example?